# How to bring local path from user PC to Azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, path, azure-functions, azureportal

How can I bring Azure a local path?

I'm trying to perform an HTTP call using Azure Function Apps (on Azure Portal), & I have to bring a path from my PC, in order this local image to be uploaded.

The request body looks something like this:

```
{  

'url'  :  'C:/Users/User/Pictures/example.jpg'

}
```

I tried to search about it & I found a solution which tells to run the Azure on local, but I want it to run on Azure portal.

I found more answer which tells that when I run a function on azure portal, the function path changes to D:\home\site\wwwroot> & by this way - I can put the image in this location; but I have no such as this path in my PC.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What function you want to implement? If you just want to pass the url from request body to Function, it's not hard to do it. If you want to upload local file to Function, you could with Function portal or go to Kudu.

Comment: I want to implement a function which gets an image, detect human faces in the image & return face rectangles; so - I have to bring the url of the image. Furthermore, What you've meant     "you could with Function portal or go to Kudu"  ??       Thanks for the attention!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of Azure blob storage to store the files that should be used by the user function. You won't know if your function will use the same files every time it is executed if it is using Consumption plan. Uploaded images should go to Blob Storage an example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=dotnet

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I havn't tried it yet, by I hope it'll work well.    Can I upload an image to Blob Storage by code ??

Comment: Yes I added a link

Comment: @SaraBenShabbat shabbat shalom! the azure function is running server-side and doesnt have access to your local machine. you will need a mechanism that will pass something the file as a parameter into your function